# Benchmarking multiple difficultyComparatorClass?

Tags: benchmarking, comparator, optaplanner

I would like to compare various options for ordering my Entities during the `ConstructionHeuristic` phase.

I have written several `difficultyComparatorClasses`.

But since the association of the class to the entity is made by an annotation on the Entity class, I cannot change it in the Benchmarker's configuration.

How would you Benchmark multiple `difficultyComparatorClass`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not possible with difficulty (which is a shame), however as an alternative you can configure a sorter comparator class on your entity selector instead of configuring difficulty, as shown in the docs here: https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.9.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#sortedSelectionByComparator.

As a second alternative, you can run separate benchmarks and merge them together in one benchmark report (https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.9.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#benchmarkReportAggregation)

Comment: Addition to the first alternative: keep in mind that when you create multiple benchmark configs with their own construction heuristic settings, it will not override the construction heuristic settings as defined in the inherited solver benchmark, but instead add it below the phases defined in the inherited solver benchmark (https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.9.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#inheritedSolverBenchmark)

Comment: Yes, it's a shame - I've run into this too and it's been on my mind to enable it, please create a jira.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help. I indeed started to implement my case with a sorter comparator class, but Iwould have liked to be able to use the "FIRST_FIT_DECREASING", "WEAKEST_FIT_DECREASING", etc. directly :) The JIRA entry is created: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1201